# Create editable autofilled form with content from node and user

Tags: forms, files

I have custom content type and I want a link inside the node that will create an editable form and auto-fill fields in the form with content from the node and content from the logged in user. The editable fields on the form will be user generated text only. Completed form will need to be downloadable pdf.